# Does the Batmobile have a music player?

Tags: dc, comics, batman

The Batmobile is equipped with numerous gadgets that help the Dark Knight fight crime. One of the gadgets is the Bat radio. The Batmobile radio has made several appearances in the comics since its introduction in ***Detective Comics #92*** and later appearing in ***Detective Comics #449*** (all the way through the movies, animated series and present comic books). The radio was primarily used to contact the police (esp. Commissioner Gordon), pick broadcasting signals from nearby vehicles and most importantly, be in continuous connection with the Bat-computer in the Bat-cave.

[image]
<sub>Source: [*Detective Comics #92*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVbp3.jpg)</sub>

[image]
<sub>Source: [*Detective Comics #449*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lw8bs.jpg)</sub>

Every other gadget fit into the Batmobile has its own purpose. And the music player seemed quite off-character to me. Because Batman doesn't seem the type who would play music while fighting crime and chasing super-villains (*Except if you count the Lego Batman who actually has a playlist for every situation*).

However, in ***Justice League: The Animated series (Season 2 Episode 5-6: Only a Dream)***, when [Doctor Destiny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Destiny) is taking down the league members one-by-one, Batman is on his way trying to stop him. To avoid falling off to sleep, Batman breaks his windshield, and starts playing loud music (on his Bat-music-player) in the Batmobile.

So, has the Bat-music-player made any comic books appearances?

Comment: The down-vote tool tip suggest down-voting if a question shows a lack of research, is unclear or not useful. This question seems to qualify for two of the three reasons. Can you maybe provide some more context into your question as to why this question may be useful and what research you may have done?

Comment: @Edlothiad I did search online but found nothing except the Batmobile's radio.

Comment: @Edlothiad It is well-known that the Batmobile has a radio (*or a Bat-radio as its all about branding* :p). But i couldn't find any evidence of a music player in the comics except the one in the animated series. So I was wondering if this idea was taken from some issue from the comics. Because Batman doesn't seem the type who plays music while fighting crime or chasing super villains.

Comment: And this is what made me curious. Maybe you could help me improve the question based on this.

Comment: I would just add some of those details into the post, I didn't down-vote as I had thought this was more than a simple whimsical thought, but just wanted to help try and improve the question. As in it's currently quite sparse. Including the existence of a "bat-radio" but whether evidence of it playing music is interesting, descriptions of batmans character and how music is out-of-character, etc.

Comment: I seem to remember Batman has a Bat-CD-or-possibly-video-CD-player in the Batcave in *Batman Returns*.

Answer (score 6):

Disclaimer: The OP has since edited their question to rule out radio from the answers. However, at least the first panel to me seems to indicate the Batmobile has a normal car radio and not just the Bat radio.

---

It would appear to have a radio, in *Batman: Battle for the Cowl Issue #1* Robin is having trouble trying to get the radio to work. From the context of the girl wanting to listen to the radio it would imply that this is a normal radio which you can listen to music through.

[image: Batman: Battle for the Cowl Issue #1]

In *Detective Comics #805* Batman is using a computer on board the Batmobile and the buttons above the screen look like they are for a normal music player/radio.

[image: Detective Comics #805 (cropped)]
<sub>Click for full page.</sub>

However, in a much earlier version of the Batmobile, from *The Brave and the Bold #111*, the radio had been swapped out for a phony one that is used for the ignition instead.

[image: The Brave and the Bold #111]

Comment: The code was BATMAN? Reaaaaally?

Comment: @Adamant I know! No was was ever going to guess that!

Comment: B-A-T-M-A-N?! That's incredible! I have the same combination on my luggage!

Comment: So Batman explains exactly how it *does* work to the Joker, meaning he has to change it afterwards -- and only so he can laugh about it? Just think of how horribly out of character that would be for Batman now... Things have changed a lot over the years.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Think of it more of the noble thing to do. By explaining it to the Joker he improves the Joker for bettering himself later and so gives himself more of a challenge later on.

Answer (score 0):

Batman Beyond's batmobile does